# In App Purchase with Subscription Model

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Does anyone have any idea of a service provider that provides In App Purchase with subscription model. I checked Urban Airship which has solution built around non-consumable approach and iLime is not available yet. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Though i am not aware of the service providers, i will be able to tell you about tracking of subscriptions.
Tracking usually needs the user's connected 5 devices to be enabled with the subscription. For this, you either have to maintain another set of user credentials on the server and ask the user to enter the credentials once the app is loaded onto each device. 
another approach is the unique userid for the device once the app is loaded. Upon installation on the second device, the same userid needs to be entered for enabling subscriptions.
Try to look out for newer version of ApalyaTv for more details.

Comment: what if I want to have several auto-renewable subscription for my single product which is already under IAP content having Non-Consumable type. Is their anyway to combine them ?